# How to use React state variables in setInterval in a handler function

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-state

I have code that looks like the code below (I cut most out to highlight the problem). I'm trying to, on a button click, call a function that calls setInterval to increment the parent component's state. What's being logged is just "0", though. The "setPercent" dispatch function seems to be working fine - after it's called I know that "percent" is being updated to 1, but when it gets back around on the next interval the console logs 0 again and the set sets to 1 again. I'm assuming that what's happening is that when the "clickHandler" function is created it's hard copying the value of "percent" rather than referencing it - I don't know why though and how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
const Component = () => {
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0)

    const clickHandler = (time) => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (percent < 100) {
                console.log('current percent', percent)
                setPercent(percent + 1)
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer)
            }
        }, time / 100)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={clickHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function form of `setState` should be useful here.  When given a function, `setState` calls the function with the current value as an argument (instead of the old value accessible vie the closure).  The following should work:

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);

    const clickHandler = (time) => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            setPercent((current) => {
                if (current < 100) {
                    console.log('current percent', current)
                    return current + 1;
                } else {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    return current;
                }
            });
        }, time / 100);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={clickHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

It doesn't feel ideal to have a side effect like `clearInterval` within a `setState` function though.  Here's a different approach using `useEffect` to stop the timer, which also enforces having a single timer (even if the button gets clicked multiple times):

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState();

    // Stop running timer when we reach 100%
    useEffect(() => {
        if (percent >= 100 && timer != null) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            setTimer(null);
        }
    }, [percent, timer]);

    const clickHandler = (time) => {
        // Stop any existing timer
        if (timer) {
            clearTimer(timer);
        }
        // Start new timer
        setTimer(setInterval(() => {
            setPercent((current) => current + 1);
        }, time / 100));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={clickHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, you're my hero! Haha thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on in here that are likely tripping you up.

First, every time percent changes then your component re-renders. This can lead to having multiple intervals running.
Second, on each re-render a new instance of the percent const is created, this means that each interval is operating with the value that it held when the interval is created, which leads to conflicting update values being sent to useState.

Given all this the best way, IMO, is to implement a timer/counter of this nature is with `useEffect` and `setTimeout`

Here's a quick code sandbox to demo a solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-voice-cu49u?file=/src/App.js

Don't feel discouraged about this, I've fallen into this trap a bunch I know the pitfalls.